# Ubuntu 22.10 connected to bluetooth keyboard but not working

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

My system is Ubuntu 22.10, I am keeping my system up to date, almost every day I am upgrading my system, my laptop is a Lenovo ThinkPad t470,
The problem is that I can't connect the wireless keyboard to my laptop via Bluetooth, the keyboard doesn't have a USB dongle so I am trying to connect it directly to the laptop, in the beginning, I couldn't connect but I installed Blueman and did it with that application, so now it shows that keyboard connected but laptop not reacting when I pressing keys on the keyboard, I made the keyboard trusted but it doesn't help, I thought that laptop doesn't receive commands from the keyboard, and in the terminal typed  'sudo btmon' as I saw it receiving commands

[image]

this is the received commands
[image]

Can anybody help me to understand how can i execute those commands on my laptop and how can I make work my keyboard with my Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem until I installed the latest version of Bluez (5.66).

Try this:

```
wget http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/bluetooth/bluez-5.66.tar.xz
tar xvf bluez-5.66.tar.xz
cd bluez-5.66
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y libusb-dev libdbus-1-dev libglib2.0-dev libudev-dev libical-dev libreadline-dev python3-docutils
./configure --enable-library
make
sudo make install
```

Then reboot.